# what is the sub-second format in sox audio duration?

Tags: sox

Been searching, and I can't seem to locate the units used in the duration of an audio file when requesting information about the file from sox. I'm using "sox --i file" to generate the info.

The duration string is like "00:00:05.51" in one file I have, but looking at online examples as I try to find this format I see duration strings like 00:00:19:986. What is that last 986? Is the format of sub-seconds in 1000's?

Seems anyplace referencing duration simply skips any mention of the format for sub-seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not confirmed, but reading from the docs and a few other sources, it looks like the seconds portion of the duration timecode is a real fraction, and not some "frames" that wraps at 24, 30, 60 or some other value. So the final numerals after the period could be any series the math happens to work out when dividing num samples by sample rate.